# How to make a widget fill the space in a VerticalLayout in GWT

Tags: gwt

Edited to include suggestions below: this code block now works to generate the layout in the screen shot;

I have a UIBinder and I'm trying to make a layout so that the content pane has a main section which fills the available width and height, pushing the footer down to the bottom. I tried this;

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<ui:style>
.eastPanel {
        background-color: #F60;
    }

    .westPanel {
        background-color: #EEE;
    }

    .northPanel {
        background-color: #39F;
    }

    .southPanel {
        background-color: #99C;
    }

    .centrePanel {
        background-color: #FFC;
    }

    .headerPanel {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #37B6CE;
    }

    .mainPanel {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #123;
    }

    .footerPanel {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #206876;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
    <g:north size='8'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
            <g:SimplePanel ui:field="northPanel" />
            <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:west size='13'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
            <g:SimplePanel ui:field="westPanel" />
            <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:west>
    <g:center>
        <g:LayoutPanel styleName="{style.centrePanel}"  ui:field="centrePanel">
            <g:layer top="0em" height="2em">
                <g:HTMLPanel  styleName="{style.headerPanel}"  ui:field="headerPanel">                  
                fixed header - usually a search box
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </g:layer>
            <g:layer top="2em" bottom="2em">
                <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.mainPanel}"  ui:field="meainPanel">
Expanding main area
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </g:layer>
            <g:layer bottom="0px" height="2em">
                <g:HTMLPanel  styleName="{style.footerPanel}" ui:field="footerPanel">

                fixed footer - maybe some copyright information
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </g:layer>
        </g:LayoutPanel>
    </g:center>

    <g:east size='0'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.eastPanel}">
            <g:Label>This is the EAST panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:east>
    <g:south size="0">
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.southPanel}">
            <g:Label>This is the SOUTH panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:south>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

`

[image]

This is the old code, that didnt work cause it was using a table to try to layout the main content area;

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:wids="urn:import:org.limepepper.JavaCart.gwt.ui.client.widgets">
<ui:style>
    .mainPanel {
        background-color: #AFC;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
    <g:north size='8'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.northPanel}">
            <g:SimplePanel ui:field="northPanel" />
            <g:Label>This is the NORTH panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:north>
    <g:west size='13'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.westPanel}">
            <g:SimplePanel ui:field="westPanel" />
            <g:Label>This is the WEST panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:west>
    <g:center>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:VerticalPanel>
                <g:HTMLPanel>
                    A heade panel
                </g:HTMLPanel>
                <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.mainPanel}">
                I want this panel to fill the space
                th
                rh
                tr
                h
                <br>
                </br>
                <br></br>
                <p></p>

                </g:HTMLPanel>
                <g:HTMLPanel>
                    Footer here
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </g:VerticalPanel>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:center>
    <g:east size='0'>
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.eastPanel}">
            <g:Label>This is the EAST panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:east>
    <g:south size="0">
        <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.southPanel}">
            <g:Label>This is the SOUTH panel</g:Label>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:south>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

`

[image]

but that doesn't fill the space, I could do this programmatically, but I presume there is some GWT method to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must realise, how `VerticalPanel` is implemented and how it lays out its child widgets. If you inspect the HTML generated by your page you will immediately see that it is implemented as a `<table>`.

Once you realise this, you can see straight away that no amount of screwing around with a `VerticalPanel` or a `<table>` tag for that matter will let you achieve the effect you desire.

The correct way of implementing the `<g:center/>` of your `DockLayoutPanel` is to use the `LayoutPanel` and use it's `<g:layer>...</g:layer>` children to position the header, footer and content. `LayoutPanel` (much like the `DockLayoutPanel`) uses absolute positioning to position its layers achieving pixel perfect placement.

So here is what it should look like:

```
...
<g:center>
  <g:layer top="0px" height="YOUR HEADER HEIGHT">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
      A heade panel
    </g:HTMLPanel>
  </g:layer>
  <g:layer top="YOUR HEADER HEIGHT" bottom="YOUR FOOTER HEIGHT">
    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.mainPanel}">
        I want this panel to fill the space
    </g:HTMLPanel>
  </g:layer>
  <g:layer bottom="0px" height="YOUR FOOTER HEIGHT">
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        Footer here
    </g:HTMLPanel>
  </g:layer>
</g:center>
...
```

It is sufficient to specify 2 coordinates on X or Y axis for a layer and the LayoutPanel will make the widget inside the layer take up all available space on the other axis. So if you specify `top` and `height` values for example the widget will take up all available space on the horizontal axis and be positioned at the `top` coordinate and have a `height` specified.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed another `DockLayoutPanel` as the `center` widget of the outer `DockLayoutPanel`.

i.e.:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
 ...
    <g:center>
            <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM" width="100%" height="100%">
                <g:center>
                    <g:HTMLPanel>
                        I want this panel to fill the space
                    </g:HTMLPanel>
                </g:center>
                <g:north size="3">
                    <g:HTMLPanel>
                        A header panel
                    </g:HTMLPanel>
                </g:north>
                <g:south size="3">
                    <g:HTMLPanel>
                        Footer here
                    </g:HTMLPanel>
                </g:south>
            </g:DockLayoutPanel>

    </g:center>
...
```

`DockLayoutPanel` is a specialized [`LayoutPanel`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/layoutmanagers/gwt/layoutpanel.html). `LayoutPanel` lets you postion things relative to the edges of itself, which is very useful (for instance) when you want something to drop to the bottom of its container. If you need something more advanced than what the `DockLayoutPanel` is giving you, I suggest you check out [`LayoutPanel`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/layoutmanagers/gwt/layoutpanel.html).

Comment: I think DocLayoutPanels can only be attached to the RootLayout, so would be ok to expand if there were no side panels

Comment: If you put the nested DocklayoutPanel into a HTMLPanel you probably have to specify explicit sizes for the HTMLPanel because it doesn't implement the RequireResize and ProvideResize interfaces. So you put it directly into the center element of the parnet DockLayoutPanel. 

@Tom H: DocklayoutPanels as all other LayoutPanels can be attached to any Panel which implements the ProvideResize interface. So you nest arbitrary numbers of LayoutPanels

Comment: @timeu Oops, I accidentally wrapped the DockLayoutPanel in the HTMLPanel. I've edited my answer to take that out.

Comment: @TomH I'm not sure what you mean. It is ok to embed LayoutPanels within LayoutPanels. The restriction is that if you are going to use layout panels anywhere in your app, the top level container of your whole app must be a RootLayoutPanel (instead of a RootPanel).